# WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Manifest

Tags: android, google-play, android-external-storage

I know that `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the Manifest file allows my android application to write to external storage. Does `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` mean also that my application will be installed automatically into the external storage of the devices from google play?

Thanks.

Comment: all applications are installed by default in internal storage, that permission allows you only to read and write at the external storage if available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE mean also that my application will be
>   installed automatically into the external storage of the devices from
>   google play?

No, however you may specify in the `<manifest>` tag the preferred install location:

```
<manifest 
          .....
          android:installLocation="preferExternal" >
```

Answer (score 2):

> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Means Your application will use external storage for reading writting purpose. It doesnt mean that your application will get installed on SD Card.

Answer (score 1):

No, this will only mean your app will ask for permission to write to external storage.

If you want your app to be installed on external storage your going to have to add the following to your apps manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
... >
```

See also: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html